# Cannot set configuration in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 4 Elastic Beanstalk deployments: 3 are Corretto 8 and the other one is Corretto 11.

On the Corretto 8 deployments, I can set new configuration without issue. On the Corretto 11 instance, however, any attempt to set a new configuration fails and causes a rollback.

The Corretto versions might not be the problem, but it's the only difference I can see. All 4 apps are Spring Boot apps that run as web servers (i.e embedded tomcat with exposed web ports). I am trying to set the exact same configuration name and value, and it only fails on the one instance.

The configuration I'm trying to set is pretty simple:

```
VALIDATE_RENEWALS = true
```

Even just trying to set `DEBUG = true` causes a failure and rollback.

I don't see a lot of information from the console about what's failing. Here is the event log:

```
2020-03-16 13:55:17 UTC-0600    INFO    The environment was reverted to the previous configuration setting.
2020-03-16 13:54:45 UTC-0600    ERROR   During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
2020-03-16 13:54:45 UTC-0600    ERROR   Failed to deploy configuration.
2020-03-16 13:54:45 UTC-0600    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-00553f4ac36afd327'. Aborting the operation.
2020-03-16 13:54:45 UTC-0600    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-03-16 13:54:45 UTC-0600    ERROR   [Instance: i-00553f4ac36afd327] Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].
2020-03-16 13:54:20 UTC-0600    INFO    Updating environment XXX's configuration settings.
2020-03-16 13:54:15 UTC-0600    INFO    Environment update is starting.
```

I've also downloaded the full set of logs for the instance and don't see anything obvious. The app stdout doesn't have any errors or exceptions, it just starts normally and then gets terminated. None of the other log files have messages around the times above, so I'm really not sure what else I can look at.

**Edit**

The times don't line up but I do see this in `eb-engine.log` file:

```
2020/03/16 17:54:38.508634 [INFO] checking whether command is applicable to this instance...
2020/03/16 17:54:38.508658 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2020/03/16 17:54:38.508665 [INFO] check whether this is an enhanced env...
2020/03/16 17:54:38.508794 [INFO] Executing instruction: StageJavaApplication
2020/03/16 17:54:38.508858 [ERROR] GetArchivedFileType with file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle failed with error open /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle: no such file or directory
2020/03/16 17:54:38.508868 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [config-deploy] - [StageJavaApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: staging java app failed with error GetArchivedFileType with file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle failed with error open /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Hey! Were you able to resolve this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @ProgrAmmar I was not...I ended up having to rebuild this particular environment a few weeks ago because it was on the Corretto 11 Beta platform that reached EOL. This gave me an opportunity to build it with the desired configuration using the non-beta Corretto 11 (I haven't tried any config updates so not sure if it's still an issue).

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved now. Didn't face it during my recent config update.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any solution?